# Require JS and running a command in the baseUrl

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, requirejs, turbogears2

So I have narrowed down my problem and was wondering if there was a solution to this or a way to get around it.

The code I have been working on in HTML uses a web frame work called turbogears.
To grab the files in turbogears it uses this command

```
<script type=text/javascript src= "${tg.url('pv/jquery-2.0.2.min.js')}"
```

Without it I get an error message like so

```
GET 'pv/jquery-2.0.2.min.js' 500 Internal Server Error
```

Now I am working on integrating my code into someone elses and I used RequireJS in my code. So in my require I have this set up

```
//HTML5
<script type=text/javascript  data-main= "${tg.url('pv/demo.js')}" src= "${tg.url('pv/require.js')}"

//JAVASCRIPT
requirejs.config({
    'baseUrl': 'src',
});

require(['pv'], function(PV) {
//code here
}
```

So I think what happens is that it runs the turbogears commands before the javascript and when it gets to the require it doesn't know how to grab the files without the turbogears command.

So I am wondering how do I run the command somehow with requireJS? Is there a simple solution? I am not too familiar with the turbogears web framework since I am just trying to integrate my code.

**THINGS I HAVE TRIED**

I have tried to just copy and paste the command in replacement of just src in the baseURL

```
requirejs.config({
    'baseUrl': "${tg.url('pv/src')}"
});
```

which doesn't work and responds with the same error.

I am thinking I would have to make each separate script tags to call each files? which might be too complicated and just down right messy code.

Any thoughts on how to tackle this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to always use

> "${tg.url('')"

. Suppose in my public directory i have a folder javascript and in that i have require.js then i can include it directly like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/javascript/require.js"></script>
```

If anywhere you use the tag ${}, then that will be evaluated before the javascript.